# Need export to PDF for the excel report created in Office Add-in (office.js)

Tags: office-js, export-to-pdf

I have a report in excel created by Office Add-in and want to export as PDF, but could not find any way. Is there any way either I can do export as PDF or write the file to one drive/sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

GetFileAysnc is one option to do this, please check [1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-preview#getFileAsync_fileType__options__callback_)